# ruby regex with variable optionals

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to parse a particular set of strings.

some examples of strings I will come accross are:

```
str = 'name[key1][key2][key3]'
str2 = 'name[key1]'
str3 = 'name'
```

Here are the respective arrays i'm hoping to get out of the strings:

```
arr1 = ['name', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3']
arr2 = ['name', 'key1']
arr3 = ['name']
```

So as you can see, the key is optional and can be a variable count.

The closest i've been able to come is this:

```
>> str = 'name[key1][key2][key3]'
"name[key1][key2][key3]"

>> str.scan(/(.+?)(\[.+?\])/)
[["name", "[key1]"], ["[key2]", "[key3]"]]
```

So, I can always do a flatten on that array, and then a gsub to get rid of brackets, but I don't want to just hack it together. I would like to be able to get it done in one shot. I considered just doing a string split at the bracket, but that also seems a bit of a bandaid approach as well. If anyone has ideas on how I can accomplish this better than regex, or how I can accomplish this correctly with the methods i'm using, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scan` and ignore the brackets:

```
str = 'name[key1][key2][key3]'
p str.scan(/[^\[\]]+/)
#=> ["name", "key1", "key2", "key3"]

str2 = 'name[key1]'
p str2.scan(/[^\[\]]+/)
#=> ["name", "key1"]

str3 = 'name'
p str3.scan(/[^\[\]]+/)
#=> ["name"]
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried the first answer that also looked most simple. Thank you all for the response, this happens to work great! regex is definately a weakpoint for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use positive lookahead / lookbehind to look for brackets to possibly exist, but exclude them from the match. Then you do not have to use `gsub` or `flatten` at all:

```
str = 'name[key1][key2][key3]'
p str.scan(/(?<=\[)?\w+(?=\])?/)
# => ["name", "key1", "key2", "key3"]
```

Read more about the Regexp class in the [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors).

Answer (score 0):

Using split??

```
str = 'name[key1][key2][key3]'
print str.split(/[\[\]]+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
str.tr('[]', '  ').split
```

Changes both `'['` and `']'` to `' '` and then splits on `' '`

If the number of characters you need to change to `' '` increases change the tr() to gsub() and modify the arguments accordingly